# How to combine UA and AW tracking tags?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-ads-api

I'm setting up Google Ads for a website that already had some code for tracking of Google Analytics

```
<!-- Global Site Tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXXXXX-XX"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments)};
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-XX');
</script>
<meta name="google-site-verification" content="................." />
```

And I need to set this up to Google Adwords to make some phone verification. Google provided this code for this subject:

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Ads: YYYYYYYYY -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=AW-YYYYYYYYY"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'AW-YYYYYYYYY');
</script>
<script>
  gtag('config', 'AW-YYYYYYYYY/X_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', {
    'phone_conversion_number': '(XXX) XXX-XXXX'
  });
</script>
```

But I don't know how to combine those two codes.

I've tried to paste both codes but the tracking stops working.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

to have it works you'll need a single initialisation script and two gtag('config' ...) calls:

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXXXXX-XX"></script>
<script>

// GTAG initialization
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments)};
  gtag('js', new Date());

// Setting up trackers
  gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-XX');
  gtag('config', 'AW-YYYYYYYYY');
  gtag('config', 'AW-YYYYYYYYY/X_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', {
        'phone_conversion_number': '(XXX) XXX-XXXX'
  });

</script>
```

gtag works seamlessly with multiple tracking properties. Here are some docs referrences: https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/7548399?hl=en ,  https://developers.google.com/gtagjs/devguide/add

Comment: Thanks for this answer and links! I was initially using `gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-XX', `AW-YYYYYYYYY');`. Instead of the solution you quoted.

Comment: hello, why using js with UA id and not AW ? with this above configurations we see several gtags configured...